# Mail body shows the code-PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, anchor, phpmailer

```
$mail->body = "<a href="www.example.com/register">Click here</a>";
```

I am used this for a phpMailer to create a link in mail body. but it shows the code like this....

```
<a href="www.example.com/register">Click here</a>
```

What to do...

Comment: You're looking for examples and tutorials - just go to [the PHPMailer wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki) and you'll find links to lots of documentation, examples and a tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this after `$mail->Body`

```
$mail->isHTML();
```

Comment: Its working....... Thanks....... can you please suggest any tutorial for PHPMailer.....

Comment: Note that it needs to be `$mail->Body` - PHP is case-sensitive for property names.

Comment: The `isHTML` call will work (though you don't need to pass the true param as it's the default), but setting `$mail->body` will not work.

Comment: yes, I coded as {$mail->Body}

Comment: Bro also suggest the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

//PHP Mail Function

```
<?php
$to = "email@youremail.com";
            $subject = "Subject Should be here";
            $message="<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
<title>Welcome to Company Name!</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='logo' style='margin-left:150px; margin-top:20px; float:left;'><a href='".$website."'><img src='".$website."images/logo.png' width='150'></a></div>
    <div class='msgtype' style='color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 310px;
    margin-top: -82px; float:left;
    width: 500px;'>
    Welcome to Matchless Property.com ".$fullname."! 
    </div><div style='clear:both;'></div>
    <div class='ondate' style='margin-left:150px; margin-top:10px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#999; font-size:14px;'>".$date."</div>
    <div class='box' style='background-color:#eeeeee; margin-top:20px;'>
        <div class='note' style='margin-left:150px; padding-top:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:28px; color:#333; width:650px; padding-bottom:20px;'>
        Welcome to Matchless Property! 
        </div>
        <div style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18; color:#666; margin-left:150px; margin-bottom:20px;'>
            <div>Hi, ".$fullname." Here it is notification mail from Matchless Property. Please verify your link below.</div>
        </div>
        <div class='forgotpassword' style='background-color: #33CCFF; padding: 6px 20px; width:85px; margin-bottom:20px; margin-left:130px;'>
            <a href='".$website."verification.php?uida56sdf4sd4f568er14dfv1=".$userRec['id']."' style='color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;'>Click Here</a>
        </div>
        <div class='quitenote' style='margin-left:150px; padding-top:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; color:#333; width:650px; padding-bottom:20px;'>
        You can now post ad and features! We are happy you are here.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='footer' style='background-color:#333; color:#999; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:20px; text-align:center; font-size:12px;'>
        <a href='".$website."' style='color:#999; text-decoration:none;'>© Matchless Property</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='".$website."terms.php' style='color:#999; text-decoration:none;'>Terms & conditions</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='".$website."privacy.php' style='color:#999; text-decoration:none;'>Privacy policy</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='http://www.dimensionsxpert.com' style='color:#999; text-decoration:none;'>Dimensions Xpert</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='".$website."contact.php' style='color:#999; text-decoration:none;'>Contact us</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>";

        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

        // More headers
        $headers .= 'From: Company Name  <no-reply@matchlessproperty.com>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Bcc: yourname@youremail.com' . "\r\n";
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question. They are using PhpMailer.

Comment: this one is good, but sometimes mails are placed in spamers.